# How to bind a key in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to know if it was possible to bind key to execute a command but while the .bat file is minimized.

Any ideas?
I have searched everywhere but I have found nothing, the only thing I found was "choice" which is something I am not trying to do.

I know that this is possible because I have a file that does it, sadly it is not mine and it was converted to a .exe file so I don't know how to convert it back to a .bat file to be able to look into the code and find my answer.

Comment: The Windows shell is *really limited*, and even the powerful shells in other systems to not have such capabliities. The only way a batch file would be able to do this would be though an external program.

Comment: How do you know that the .exe was first written as a .bat file? This is just not possible with standard Batch! Perhaps is it a function of the bat-to-exe "compiler"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of hotkeys in Windows. One to activate an open window (set when window is created) and one that sends a message `key pressed` to a window (set by a program anytime).

On Windows shortcuts (ie lnk files not keyboard shortcuts) there is an option to set a hotkey. If the program is not running then windows' explorer registers it to itself and starts the program in the shortcut, if the program is running activates the window.